# Using RInside in a Qt 5.5.1 app under Windows 7

Tags: c++, r, qt

I'm currently working on a Qt 5.5 project and would like to perform some calls to my R interpreter ( I'm using R 3-3-1 on my Windows 7 system ) to perform some stats calculations. I have to precise that I use the Qt 5.5 MSVC 2013 kit that I configured to use the MSVC 12.0 compiler.

Of course, I've already installed the R packages Rcpp and RInside.

Following Dirk Eddelbuettel work on this subject, I've tried to adapt its **.pro** file to make work [the Qtdensity example](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25/) but I'm encountering problems when compiling the .pro file.

Actually, here are the outputs for the different variables and flags produced by the compilation of the .pro file and my questions in regard of each of these :

Project MESSAGE: R_HOME is C:\R\R-3.3.1   ***So far, so good...***

Project MESSAGE: RLDFLAGS is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lR -lm  **is it ok ?**

Project MESSAGE: RBLAS is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lRblas  **is it ok ?**

Project MESSAGE: RLAPACK is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack **is it ok ?**

Project MESSAGE: RCPPINCL is -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include **it seems ok..**

Project MESSAGE: RCPPLIBS is       **Souldn't be empty, right ?...**

Project MESSAGE: RINSIDEINCL is -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/include **it seems ok...**

Project MESSAGE: RINSIDELIBS is "C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/lib/x64/libRInside.a" **Should I use libRInside.dll instead ?**

and finally, when I try to compile Qtdensity anyway, I come across the following error :

**C:\R\R-3.3.1\library\RInside\include\RInsideCommon.h:27: erreur : C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/time.h': No such file or directory**

Of course, I'm not a senior C++ architect , but if someone could help me to find out what values SHOULD take the different variables of the .pro file according to my system and environnment features, that would be awesome because I'd REALLY like capitalizing on my learning time in R and avoiding learning Python -:)

Best regards.

Julien

----------------------EDIT----------------------------

Ok,here are some news :

1) I've installed R 3.3.1 under the C:\R\R-3.3.1 directory.
2) I also tried to create a new compilation kit that I've named **Mingw 32bit R** whose configuration is :

**compiler** :  C:\R\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\g++.exe

**debugger** : C:\R\Rtools\mingw_32\bin\gdb.exe

**Qt Version** : Qt 5.7.0 MingW 32 bit.

I think I get the .pro variables correctly all set by now :

Project MESSAGE: R_HOME is C:\R\R-3.3.1

Project MESSAGE: RCPPFLAGS is -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/include -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/include/x64

Project MESSAGE: RLDFLAGS is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lR -lm

Project MESSAGE: RBLAS is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lRblas

Project MESSAGE: RLAPACK is -LC:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/x64 -lRlapack

Project MESSAGE: RCPPINCL is -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include

Project MESSAGE: RCPPLIBS is  **<-OK...**

Project MESSAGE: RINSIDEINCL is -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/include

Project MESSAGE: RINSIDELIBS is "C:/R/3.3.1/library/RInside/lib/x64/libRInside.a"

....but at compile time, I get the following errors...

```
C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.3/library/RInside/examples/qt/build-qtdensity-Mingw_32_bit_Rtools-Debug'
g++ -c -pipe -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/include -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/include/x64 -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include -IC:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/include -g -std=gnu++11 -frtti -Wall -Wextra -fexceptions -mthreads -DUNICODE -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I../../qt -I. -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtSvg -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtCore -Idebug -IC:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o debug/qtdensity.o ../qtdensity.cpp
In file included from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/combaseapi.h:155:0,
                 from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/objbase.h:14,
                 from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/ole2.h:17,
                 from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wtypes.h:12,
                 from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/winscard.h:10,
                 from C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/windows.h:97,
                 from C:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtCore/qt_windows.h:61,
                 from C:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui/qopengl.h:49,
                 from C:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui/qopenglcontext.h:60,
                 from C:/Qt/5.7/mingw53_32/include/QtGui/QtGui:32,
                 from ../qtdensity.h:13,
                 from ../qtdensity.cpp:8:
C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/objidlbase.h:864:18: error: macro "Realloc" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
         SIZE_T cb) = 0;
                  ^
C:/R/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/objidlbase.h:864:22: error: 'Realloc' declared as a 'virtual' field
         SIZE_T cb) = 0;
                      ^
In file included from C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R.h:75:0,
                 from C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:52,
                 from C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:29,
                 from C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/include/RInsideCommon.h:38,
                 from C:/R/R-3.3.1/library/RInside/include/RInside.h:26,
                 from ../qtdensity.h:11,
                 from ../qtdensity.cpp:8:
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:37: error: expected identifier before '(' token
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                     ^
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:47: error: 'parameter' declared as function returning a function
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                               ^
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:50: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                                  ^
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:37: error: expected identifier before '(' token
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                     ^
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:47: error: 'parameter' declared as function returning a function
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                               ^
C:/R/R-3.3.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:71:50: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 #define Free(p)        (R_chk_free( (void *)(p) ), (p) = NULL)
                                                  ^
Makefile.Debug:797: recipe for target 'debug/qtdensity.o' failed
```

Clearly, there are still problems with some include files ( is it due to a discrepancy between Qt 5.7.0 framework / mingw-compiled libraries and the Mingw version supplied by RTools ? Any ideas ?

Best regards.

Julien

Comment: Thanx for your comments gentlemen, I'll try to install a mingw-compiled version of Qt and make it all work...

Answer (score 1):

You missed questions 1.3 and particular 2.9 of the [Rcpp FAQ vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf).

Allow me to repeat 2.9 here again (from source, the pdf is prettier, and hand-adapted for the markdown here):

> #### Can I use `Rcpp` with Visual Studio ?
>
> Not a chance.
>
> And that is not because we are meanies but because `R` and
>   Visual Studio simply do not get along. As `Rcpp` is all about
>   extending `R` with `C++` interfaces, we are bound by
>   the available toolchain.  And `R` simply does not compile
>   with Visual Studio. Go complain to its vendor if you are still upset.

But fear not:  you **can** build on Windows with Qt and have RInside.  But you must used MinGW all the way.  Way back when I needed to build Qt from source to make this happen, these days I believe you will get a suitable library prebuilt.   Still, if you run into issues do build it from source *to have the same toolchain* throughout your project.  This can be critically important with C++.

Answer (score 1):

The `.dll` is a library linked at runtime. The linker needs an `.a` or `.lib` file.

`RCPPLIBS` will be empty with Rcpp (>= 0.11.0) and can be omitted.

The error you're facing is because apparently Rinside was not meant to be compiled with Visual C++. `sys/time.h` is not provided by MSVC.

You're trying to use a version of Rinside that was compiled with gcc (most likely mingw). This won't work since you can't mix C++ libraries compiled using different compilers. Everything must be compiled using the same compiler. Since compiling `R` using MSVC requires patching *lots* of code, you have to switch to mingw and either use Qt compiled with the same mingw version, or recompile Qt using mingw that was used for Rinside.

Comment: R simply does not build under MSCV.  Hence no Rcpp.  Hence no RInside.   See my answer my preceded yours by a few seconds.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Unless I'm mistaken, R itself exposes only a C interface, and on Windows the C ABI interoperates between all sorts of compilers, even non-C, so you could definitely compile Rcpp under MSVC and it could consume R dll compiled under mingw. It seems some of R's headers might need a tweak or two.